# PDF for Countinous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $A,B,C$ be distributed such that $A$ is uniformly with $U((1,2.5))$, $B$ is exponentialy $Exp(0.3)$ and $C$ is normal with $N(0,8.5)$. Which of these - if any - does there exist some interval $(c,d)$ such that the pdf is strictly greater than $1$ on $(c,d)$

**My answer**

Does not exists as the pdf can only be 1 for the simple distributions at max. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the same problem I have that now λ=2 and thus B is Exp(2) and another r.v Y:=X2 how do i show the pdf of Y is given by

First you have to state if $\lambda$ is the "rate" or "scale" parameter as the exponential has 2 different parametrizations...let's assume that your density is

$$f_X(x)=2e^{-2x}$$

If you want to derive the density of

$$Y=X^2$$

simply observe that your transformation function is monotonic thus

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{e^{-2\sqrt{y}}}{\sqrt{y}}$$

this because you can use the following formula (that is often named as "Fundamental transformation theorem"

$$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|$$

Comment: Ahh so $c=-1/2$?

Comment: I have just started with transformations so it is a bit strange to me still. But I see that $c=-1/2$

Comment: This is correct right? As in the transformation $y$ would be reciprocal and taken the square root.

Comment: Hello Tommik. Could you help me out with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104442/pmf-for-a-vector-a-b-c

Answer (score -1):

the pdf is a "density" of probability, not a probabilty, thus it can be also $\infty$

for example, take $X\sim U(0;0.5)$,  you have that

$$f_X(x)=2$$

$\forall x \in (0;0.5)$

Comment: oh so all of them actually can?

Comment: no, of course....for example in the first case, the uniform one, $f_X(x)=2/3$

Comment: Ok I see. I am thinking only the uniformly and the normal distributed one can be strictly bigger and exponentiel is limited above at 1.

Comment: Would this be the correct assessment?

Comment: @mathstudent23: actually your answer is correct but your reasoning is wrong. Assuming that for the exponential 0.7 is the rate parameter, none of their pdf can be greater than 1

Comment: Ok I actually see. In the same problem I have that now $\lambda=2$ and thus $B$ is $Exp(2)$ and another r.v $Y:=X^2$ how do i find a constant $c$ so that the pdf of $Y$ is given by $y^c \cdot exp(-2y^½)$

Comment: @mathstudent23: consider this exponential pdf: $f(x)=2e^{-2x}$. Obviously it can be greater than 1

Comment: this extra problem related to the exponentiel is causing me problems as I have never seen such before. I was thinking that I had to square the expression for $X$ thus $X:=4exp(-4x)$ and solve for $c$ when I equal this expression with the $pdf$ of $Y$ but that does not seem productive.